# Streaming from ip camera

Tags: ios, video-streaming, rtsp, ip-camera

I am working on 1 project start up. And i want to do the following this. 1)Detect the camera by wifi and camera id. 2)After detecting the camera.Fetch the stream from the camera to the phone 3)play that stream into the player.

Now i had done google and found that by RTSP we can achieve the following this. But i am not sure or dont have the code to detect the camera from the camera id or by wifi and the detect the stream from that. Can anyone guide me in this with the some sample source code.

Answer (score 0):

If your camera supports ONVIF you can use [it](http://www.onvif.org/Documents/Specifications.aspx) to detect it.